# Protection for a diplomatic mission

Tags: magic, military, diplomacy

On a diplomatic mission, how many men would be reasonable to ensure an ambassador's protection and what rank would they be? It's a diplomatic mission to secure an arranged marriage between two kingdoms who haven't had a relationship before. The marriage is already agreed upon, and they're escorting the prince to make it official and negotiate an official treaty. There is a third kingdom that would not find this particularly pleasing and there is an element of danger. It is a fantasy world. Thus the level of technology is swords, shields and armour, with a little flavour of magic.

Comment: Hey there, it's a diplomatic mission to secure an arranged marriage between two kingdoms who haven't had a relationship before. The marriage is already agreed upon, and they're escorting the prince to make it official and negotiate an official treaty. There is a third kingdom that would not find this particularly pleasing and there is an element of danger. When I say fantasy world, I mean swords, shields and armour, a little flavour of magic.

Comment: Comments may vanish without notice.  Stuff relevant to the question should be written into it, so we have it permanently.

Comment: They *must* have had diplomatic relations before or they would not have moved to the point of having an arranged marriage.  That would take a considerable amount of negotiation and, more importantly, a specific reason for seeking such a relationship.  Arranged marriages happened *after* the treaty negotiation, not before.  They were part of the result, not part of the negotiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big question here is the third kingdom.  Plus any random bandits or pirates that might attach a party small enough.

So, is there a route by which the kingdom can expect to ward off attacks from the third kingdom by sheer force?  If you can go by the plains, where there is a trade route that is on the other side of the kingdom from the third, so you have a good road and no good place for ambush, it would be enough to have a force capable of dealing with the troops that the other kingdom could get to that road.  Likewise, going by sea requires ships enough to deal with the other navy if that's feasible.  Such an escort may be seriously pared down when he reaches a position at which the other kingdom's force can be reasonably expected to protect the prince -- they may go home, or hang around on the border to escort back the newly-weds -- or accompany him all the way to escort him back after.

If it's not feasible -- you have to go through a forest where ambush is easy, their navy is so much larger than you can't field one -- you need a very small party traveling incognito.  His escort in the kingdom will probably be already in the service of the ambassador, possibly beefed by up other incognito travelers.  Once there, since the kingdom could overwhelm his side, the purpose is

- To prevent random attacks
- To possibly buy him time for escape in event of treachery
- To hold off assassins from the third kingdom long enough for the other kingdom's forces to arrive
- To do him honor (and impress on the kingdom the pomp that his own kingdom can maintain)

Answer (score 7):

Any diplomatic mission will be vulnerable to attack by the host government. The host government can *always* send enough troops to overwhelm them. So the bodyguards have two or possibly three purposes:

- Protect the ambassador against *unsanctioned* attacks.
- Satisfy the honor and status of the ambassador.
- Assure that any *sanctioned* attack will not go silently. One body can be explained as a hunting accident, half a dozen are an overt hostility.

So the bodyguards would most likely be [personal retainers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affinity_(medieval)) of the ambassador, assuming the ambassador has such people. The dividing line between a groom, a valet, and a bodyguard might be hard to draw. Their number depends on the status of the ambassador (is he or she from the high nobility?) and the number of other members in the party.

When [Peter the Great](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Embassy_of_Peter_the_Great) went to western Europe, he had 70 troops, but then he was a Czar. That should be seen as the absolute upper limit.

Comment: A 4th purpose is to provide protection long enough to effect escape.  In modern times, this means until helicopter evac arrives.  OP mentions magic, maybe they could stall until the magic escape portal is ready.

Comment: @Ryan_L, that would be my first paragraph. The guard force of an embassy cannot hold out, unless there are cases llike Iraq in 2005 or thereabouts -- extremely strong guards, rescue forces nearby. Could you imagine the Marines in the US embassy in Moscow holding out for rescue?